# How do I create Page Object Model that works for Android AND iOS in Appium Java

Tags: java, selenium, appium, pageobjects, page-factory

I have created a Page Object in Java with Appium and Selenium that is currently working for an Android app as shown below:

```
public class MattVerifyPage extends PageObject{

private AppiumDriver driver = FrameworkInitialize.driver;

By verifyTitle = By.xpath("/hierarchy/android.widget.TextView");

public void verifyTitle(String expectedTitle){

String actualTitle = driver.findElement(verifyTitle).getText();
```

However, I need it to work an the Android app and the iOS app, the xpath selector is different for both apps. I think I need to do something like this:

```
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = “androidxpath”)
@iOSFindBy(xpath = “iOSxpath”)
public MobileElement verifyTitle ;
```

This would mean regardless of whether I am using Android or iOS I would still just use the one variable called 'verifyTitle'.

However, when I do this, the driver.findElement line (String actualTitle = driver.findElement(verifyTitle).getText() shows the following error:

```
findElement
(org.openqa.selenium.By)
in DefaultGenericMobileDriver cannot be applied
to
(io.appium.java_client.MobileElement)
```

I think I am comparing AppiumElements with SeleniumElements but I’m not sure how to resolve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: You've almost got it.  Research page factory for your solution.  Page factory initializes the elements, so you don't do a driver.findElement(...) but instead have the web elements already initialized.  You still want to encapsulate them in the page object, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, lots of mixing of object types in your original example. You're on the right track with the @OSFindBy annotations. Once you have those defined you already have the element so no need to find it again. The following would be all you'd need:

```
verifyTitle.getText()
```

See this blog post for more information on the [Page Object Model](https://blog.testproject.io/2018/07/31/page-object-model-appium-java-android/) (POM).

Summary:

```
import all the good stuff including PageFactory;

public class YourPage {
  private WebDriver driver;

  public YourPage(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
  }

  @AndroidFindBy(id = "android_button")
  @iOSFindBy(id = "ios_button")
  private MobileElement that_button;

  public void pushTheButton() {
    that_button.click()
  }
}
```

Note: above code is untested / written off the top of my head / I don't write Java for a living. Prone to error, but should give you the idea.

Comment: Since **@iOSFindBy** is depreciated in java-client version 7.0.0, you can use **@iOSXCUITFindBy** instead of iOSFindBy

Answer (score 0):

This Working with Me, My Project Selenium, TestNG and Appium use PageFactory.initElements

```
public class Login extends Setup {

    @Test
    public void loginAlert() throws InterruptedException {
        

    Button button = new Button(driver);
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, button);
            Input input = new Input(driver);
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, input);
        
        
        Input input1 = new Input(driver);
        System.out.println("Test Alert Login");
        button.ById("navigation_more");
        button.ById("btnLogin");
        input.ById("et_email_or_phone_number", "dikakoko.com");
        input1.ById("tet_password", "dikakoko");
        
    }
}
```

Below this is the function I called above.

```
public class Input {
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    Root root = new Root();

    public Input(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void ById(String selector, String textValue) {
        MobileElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(root.element() + ":id/" + selector));
        waitForVisible(driver, element);
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element);
        actions.click();
        actions.sendKeys(textValue);
        actions.build().perform();
        System.out.println("Input: " + textValue);
    }
    
    private void waitForVisible(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver, MobileElement element) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Waiting for element visibility");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and This

```
public class Button {

    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    Root root = new Root();

    public Button(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void ById(String selector) {
        MobileElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(root.element() + ":id/" + selector));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element);
        actions.click();
        actions.build().perform();
        System.out.println("Button is Clicked!");
    }
}
```

I Use This

```
Button button = new Button(driver);
PageFactory.initElements(driver, button);
Input input = new Input(driver);
PageFactory.initElements(driver, input);
```

My References : [From www.seleniumeasy.com](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/page-factory-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver)